# Delete from multiple tables at once in azure

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying this SQL statement to delete from two tables at once but i find that it is only deleting from one table and giving me an error

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__cc_custom__custo__02084FDA". The conflict occurred in database "CurtainClub", table "dbo.cc_customer_address", column 'customer_number'.`

My sql statement is as follows:

```
BEGIN
SELECT * from cc_customer 
inner join cc_customer_address on customer_id=customer_number

delete from cc_customer where customer_id=3
delete from cc_customer_address where customer_number=3
END
```

Also please note that `customer_number` is the foreign key of `customer_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should swap `DELETE` statements:

```
BEGIN
  SELECT * 
  from cc_customer 
  inner join cc_customer_address on customer_id=customer_number;

  delete from cc_customer_address where customer_number=3;  -- first child
  delete from cc_customer where customer_id=3;              -- then parent
END
```

Comment: I think you mean customer_number=2